# Calculating average from a list of lists without using Numpy and Pandas?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists in Python that looks like this

```
[['Wednesday', '-0.0357142857142857'],
 ['Thursday', '0.0092592592592593'],
 ['Wednesday', '1.0933999999999993']]
```

How can I calculate the average/mean from a list of lists in Python For the 2nd Column For Wednesday only without using Numpy and Pandas? So basically (-0.0357142857142857 + 1.0933999999999993) / 2

I tried

```
for row in list_of_lists:
    if row[0] == 'Wednesday':
        print(row[1])
```

Comment: Have you tried loops?

Comment: I did try, but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: Take a look at the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) module in Python's standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab only the 2nd item (index 1) from each sub-list if the day is Wednesday, convert from string to float, then do the calculation.  Using list comprehension is a faster way to iterate, and it's the same concept as a for loop.

```
list_of_lists = [['Wednesday', '-0.0357142857142857'], ['Thursday', '0.0092592592592593'], ['Wednesday', '1.0933999999999993']]

list_of_col2_wed = [float(sub_list[1]) for sub_list in list_of_lists if sub_list[0] == 'Wednesday']
list_average = sum(list_of_col2_wed) / len(list_of_col2_wed)

print(list_of_col2_wed)
print(list_average)
# [-0.0357142857142857, 1.0933999999999993]
# 0.5288428571428567
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dictionaries`:

```
d = dict()

for key, val in lst:
    if d.get(key) is None:
        d[key] = {'val' : 0, 'count' : 0}
    count = d[key]['count']
    d[key]['val'] =  (d[key]['val'] * count + float(val))/(count + 1)
    d[key]['count'] += 1
    
 d   
{'Wednesday': {'val': 0.5288428571428567, 'count': 2},
 'Thursday': {'val': 0.0092592592592593, 'count': 1}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could

- Convert the list of lists into a DataFrame
- Convert the second column to float type (because its a string now)
- Compute the mean of second column grouped by first column
- Retrieve the mean for Wednesday

Below are the steps in python code

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_lists = [['Wednesday', '-0.0357142857142857'], ['Thursday', '0.0092592592592593'], ['Wednesday', '1.0933999999999993']]
df= pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists, columns=['weekday','value'])
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(float)
mean_by_day = df.groupby('weekday')['value'].mean()
result = mean_by_day['Wednesday']
```